# How to get from orders how many of selected product was sold - programatically?

Tags: magento-1.9, products, sales, programmatically

Trying to get number of sold product from orders within range of time.
How can I do it ... easiest possible method ?

I can get a whole collection of orders from selected range of time, then get all the items from each order and then loop trough so at the end i'll get what I want but this seems to be a bit complicated and code will be probably quiet big :).
Is this the only way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of three ways at the moment - depending on your requirements for further processing not all may be applicable/helpful though:

The closest way you can get in "default Magento" would be `Reports > Products > Products Orderer` in backend. There you can filter for a data range (from/to date).
Further processing of the data would usually be offline (e.g. CSV or XML export).
[[image]

Else, a shady direct `SELECT` on `sales_flat_order_item` (you may want to combine that on with a join on `sales_flat_orders` to furthermore filter on certain order states and other for you relevant indicators). A valid reason for doing this might be a HUGE table of created orders and/or you have to access the data remotely (but even in this scenario other methods might be preferred).

And last but not least (at least from my end for the moment) would be a combination of both - aka what would Magento do? Well, if we take a look at the reports module's collections (i.e. `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` and `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Sold_Collection`) we can see, that Magento actually doesn't really do much more than firing joined `SELECT`s. As an example, if you'd just modify (for a quick test obviously, in real life you'd override the function) the function `addOrderedQty()` in `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` from `->where('parent_item_id IS NULL')` to `->where('order_items.product_id = 12345')` you'd get the result for this product only.

I hope I've been able to point out some to you relevant directions.

Comment: Oooh hello Christ, it's you again :)

Comment: The question actually is how can I do it programatically using collections and all available Magento methods as the SQL is a stupidly complicated if you want get data from multiple tables (probably I could do it but if I can do it just using collections ..... should be much easier).

Comment: Would be even better if I could get this information using Magento API, I know how to pull products, how to get orders but how to count sold products from orders ..... no idea ;)

Comment: @RobertA. - Hiho ;) Actually you're right. My post in fact doesn't respect your question in a good way (I read your question, thought about the reports module mentioned in point 3, figured _wait, why don't you just..._) and kind of missed the initial intention. Though, a rewrite as scratched in 3 in order to extend the functionality of the reports module is not an option? If you'd like to go for an API-based solution I'd suggest that you may update your question and I'd just delete my post :)